# Is the sequence $\log(n) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$ bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, upper-lower-bounds

Been looking at the sequence $\big{(}\log(n) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}\big{)}$, it seems like its bounded but I am not sure if it is. Is it? and if so is this a result I can see a reference for?

Comment: Your sequence looks like the one for the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: @player3236 yup thats it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that
$$
log(n)=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}
$$
Now look at the sum and think about how the Riemann-Darboux integral.

Let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 1):

Using harmonic numbers
$$\Delta_n=\log(n) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}=\log(n)-H_{n-1}$$ For large values of $p$
$$H_p=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
$$\Delta_n=-\gamma +\log \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)-\frac{1}{2 (n-1)}+\cdots$$